# C# Winforms .Net 5: Load() of base UC is called before Ctor of derived UC is executed

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls, .net-5

We have migrated our projects from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net 5.
Now we see a very strange issue: If the display language of our application is set to something different than English, we get an Exception during the application start. If it remains in English, everything is fine.

The exception is raised in a UserControl with 3 levels of inheritance:

- base, `UCImageObject`
- derived #1 `UCImageObjectStandard : UCImageObject`
- derived #2 `UCImgObjStd_Circle : UCImageObjectStandard`

The problem is that the `Load` event of one `UCImageObject` is somehow executed before the constructor of `UCImageObjectStandard`: The `Load()` method of `UCImageObject` calls a virtual `Init()` method, which is overridden in `UCImageObjectStandard`. The `UCImageObjectStandard.Init()` is then executed before the `UCImageObjectStandard..ctor`, which of course is wrong, and in our case this causes the exception.

I assume that this is indirectly caused by the execution of some events (likely `Layout`, maybe `TextChanged`) of labels or other controls, that are directly or indirectly nested inside the `UCImageObject` or `UCImageObjectStandard`. The events may be raised by the changes to the `Text` property due to the changed language. The coded texts are in english, and their content does not change when our language database set its english texts on the controls, since they are identical. But the texts of other languages of course are different.

The strange thing is, that this has worked well for years in .Net Framework 4.8. But it seems that changes have been made in .Net Core or .Net 5, so that the `Load` event of an UC may be called earlier than before.

**Can anybody tell me what has changed?**
**It's wrong to call an overridden method in the ctor of classes that use inheritance. But should we also avoid calling an overridden method in the `Load` event?**

I have debugged it as far as I could now, including stepping through the .Net 5 source files.
The stacktrace of the failing execution is written below (frame numbers added myself; line numbers not added since they are mostly wrong in the .Net files).
The wrong execution path starts somewhere above stack frame 43.
I could prove that the texts of a label (used in stacktrace frames 58 to 63) are non-English already.

```
82   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObject.UCImageObject_Load(Object i_sender, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
81   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
80   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
79   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
78   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
77   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
76   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
75   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
74   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
73   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
72   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
71   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
70   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
69   at Interop.User32.CreateWindowExW(WS_EX dwExStyle, Char* lpClassName, String lpWindowName, WS dwStyle, Int32 X, Int32 Y, Int32 nWidth, Int32 nHeight, IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hMenu, IntPtr hInst, Object lpParam)
68   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
67   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
66   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
65   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_ShowKeyboardCues()
64   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.CreateTextFormatFlags(Control control, ContentAlignment textAlign, Boolean showEllipsis, Boolean useMnemonic)
63   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.CreateTextFormatFlags(Size constrainingSize)
62   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSizeCore(Size proposedConstraints)
61   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
60   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
59   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_PreferredSize()
58   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
57   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleControl(SizeF factor, BoundsSpecified specified)
56   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleControl(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
55   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
54   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleChildControls(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl, Boolean updateWindowFontIfNeeded)
53   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
52   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleChildControls(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl, Boolean updateWindowFontIfNeeded)
51   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
50   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleChildControls(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl, Boolean updateWindowFontIfNeeded)
49   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
48   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleChildControls(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl, Boolean updateWindowFontIfNeeded)
47   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.Scale(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)
46   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.PerformAutoScale(Boolean includedBounds, Boolean excludedBounds)
45   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.PerformNeededAutoScaleOnLayout()
44   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnLayoutResuming(Boolean performLayout)
43   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout(Boolean performLayout)
42   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObjectStandard.InitializeComponent()
41   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObjectStandard..ctor()
40   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImgObjStd_Circle..ctor()
29   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObject.Create(EnumType i_type, UCImageObject& io_ucImageObject)
28   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObject.ShowData(UCImageObject& io_ucImageObject, CImageObject i_imageObject)
27   at DI.UIWF.UCJobCreatorSettings.ucImageObjectList_SelectionChanged(Object i_oSender, EventArgs i_oEventArgs)
26   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObjectList.OnSelectionChanged(Int32 i_imageObjectID)
25   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObjectList.dgvImageObjects_SelectionChanged(Object i_sender, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
24   at SMCore.UIWF.UCImageObjectList.ShowData(CImageObjectList i_imageObjectList)
23   at DI.UIWF.UCJobCreatorSettings.Init(CImageObjectList i_oImageObjectList, IList`1 i_listoImageAcquisitionDeviceInfo)
22   at DI_JobEditor.UIWF.frmMain.Init_UI_Settings()
21   at DI_JobEditor.UIWF.frmMain.frmMain_Load(Object i_oSender, EventArgs i_oEventArgs)
20   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
19   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
18   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
17   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
16   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
15   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
14   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
13   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
12   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
11   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
10   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
09   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
08   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
07   at Interop.User32.ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, SW nCmdShow)
06   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
05   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
04   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
03   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop reason, ApplicationContext context)
02   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
01   at DI_JobEditor.UIWF.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**EDIT**
I have found the place where the code executions differ based on English or non-English language. It's in stack frame 56:
`System.Windows.Forms.Control.ScaleControl(SizeF includedFactor, SizeF excludedFactor, Control requestingControl)`
The line is 10131 (.Net 5.0.13):
`if (includedSpecified != BoundsSpecified.None)`

If the language remains English, the label's text is not changed (The label is a child of `UCTolerance`, which is a child of `UCImageObjectStandard`). Therefore, the label's size also stays the same (`Label.AutoSize=true`). And then there is no need to scale the control (`UC.AutoScaleMode = Dpi`).

This means there are 3 ways to avoid the unwanted execution paths:

1. If the UCTolerance's `AutoScaleMode` was not `DPI`, then the condition
   `if (AutoScaleMode != AutoScaleMode.None && AutoScaleMode != AutoScaleMode.Inherit)`
   in `ContainerControl.PerformAutoScale(bool,bool)` would be false, and all the `Scale`-methods would never be executed.
2. If the Label's `AutoSize` was not true, then the control would not be resized, and there likely would not be a need to scale it.
3. If the text was not changed, then the above mentioned condition
   `if (includedSpecified != BoundsSpecified.None)`
   would be false, because `includedSpecified`, which is set by `Control.RequiredScaling` (line 10116), would remain `None` and not become `Size`.

#3 is no option, because the texts must be set according to the chosen language.
But I can easily implement #1 and #2, because I can use labels with fixed size and adapt their size in the `Layout` event of the `UCTolerance`, if needed. And I can set `UCTolerance.AutoScaleMode=None`, because we don't use AutoScale anyway.

But the questions persist, see above.

**EDIT**
Repro solution at https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/files/7962713/di-software.zip

Comment: Please post a very [MCVE].

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I will, as soon as I have an idea how to create it. No chance for that so far. The application contains 17 more or less large DLLs.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it, then there's very low chance for you and others to be able to solve it. It should be pretty straightforward based on your explanation, 10-20 lines of code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks, I know. Still trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answers in my report https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6565 at GitHub, this is a bug in .NET 5, which is fixed in .NET 6 and 7.